# PHP Could not find/open font

Tags: php, fonts

I am trying to write text over an image but i get the error : PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/html/anti-bot/image.php on line 12.

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$text = rand(1000,1000000);
$_SESSION['code']=$text;
$img= imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$R = rand(0,100);
$G = rand(0,100);
$B = rand(0,100);
$TxtColor = imagecolorallocate($img,$R,$G,$B);
imagettftext($img,rand(40,45),rand(0,1),rand(10,70),rand(38,50),$TxtColor,$font,$text);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

I have tried :

```
$font = 'var/www/html/anti-bot/arial.ttf";
$font = 'var/www/html/anti-bot/arial";
$font = 'arial.ttf";
$font = 'arial";
```

All files are in the same directory , var/www/html/anti-bot

Comment: Re your "I have tried"... examples: the first two are invalid (broken quotes). Also have you tried with a leading slash ... ie `/var/www/.....`

Comment: In what folder/file is your 'code' located.

Comment: It worked with /var/www/..... .Thank you , Simba.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give absolute path for reading font.

So give font path as below:

```
$font = "/var/www/html/anti-bot/arial.ttf";
```

Note `/` before `var` which take path from root directory